# How to find the first row with min value of a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where I am trying to get the row of min value by subtracting the abs difference of two columns to make a third column where I am trying to get the first or second min value of the data frame of col[3] I get an error. Is there a better method to get the row of min value from a column[3].

```
df2 = df[[2,3]]
df2[4] = np.absolute(df[2] - df[3])
#lowest = df.iloc[df[6].min()]
    2   3   4
0   -111    -104    7
1   -130    110     240
2   -105    -112    7
3   -118    -100    18
4   -147    123     270
5   225     -278    503
6   102     -122    224

                2   3   4
```

desired result = 2   -105 -112 7

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: also a warning A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get difference to `Series`, add [`Series.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.abs.html) and then compare by minimal value in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = (df[2] - df[3]).abs()
df = df[s == s.min()]
```

If want new column for diffence:

```
df['diff'] = (df[2] - df[3]).abs()
df = df[df['diff'] == df['diff'].min()]
```

Another idea is get index by minimal value by [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) and then select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), for one row DataFrame are necessary `[[]]`:

```
s = (df[2] - df[3]).abs()
df = df.loc[[s.idxmin()]]
```

EDIT:

For more dynamic code with convert to integers if possible use:

```
def int_if_possible(x):
    try:
        return x.astype(int)
    except Exception:
        return x

df = df.apply(int_if_possible)
```

Comment: if I have a list Iam converting to df...t = [x.split('\n') for x in text_scores]...to....df = pd.DataFrame(t)....is there a better way than.... df[2] = df[2].astype('int')... df[3] = df[3].astype('int')..... before....s = (df[2] - df[3]).abs()...df = df[s == s.min()]

Comment: @devlops_s - Do you want convert all columns? like `df = pd.DataFrame(t).astype(int)` ?

Comment: some cols are strings... df = pd.DataFrame(t,dtype=int64) but all cols come out strings

Comment: @jezrael....df = pd.DataFrame(t).astype(int)...... ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cap -13'

Comment: @devlops_s - it means there is some not numeric values like `cap -13`, what should necessary do with `cap -13` ? It should be `NaN` or `13` in output? There is possible more values like `cap -13` in data?

Comment: yes. but some cols only have numeric only would I have to specify which cols are numeric  or is there a catch all like dtype = int64 which will convert  numeric cols if possible.